# How to fix "- _tkinter.TclError: no events specified in binding"

Tags: python, tkinter

I found the source code somewhere on the internet
a simple program to create a window with the option
entering mathematical operations and displaying from the keyboard
the result.This is code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from math import *

def evaluate(event):
    res.configure(text="Result: " + str(eval(entry.get())))

w = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(w, text="Your Expression:").pack()
entry = tk.Entry(w)
entry.bind("event", evaluate)
entry.pack()
res = tk.Label(w)
res.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

I'm getting an error:

> C:\Users\rob\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   "C:/Users/rob/Desktop/new test.py" Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "C:/Users/rob/Desktop/new test.py", line 12, in 
>       entry.bind("", evaluate)   File "C:\Users\rob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1248, in bind
>       return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)   File "C:\Users\rob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1203, in _bind
>       self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
>   _tkinter.TclError: no events specified in binding

Please help. Im starting learning Python and I don't know a solution.

Comment: For me your example is running without an error message. I am using python 3.7.0 and tkinter version 8.6. You can figure out the tkinter version with `print(tk.TkVersion)`

Comment: I also have python 3.7.0 and tkinter 8.6 and works for me as answered 1966bc,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's clear in your reported error,

"...no events specified in binding"

change this

```py
    entry.bind('<event>', evaluate)
```

with this

```py
    entry.bind("<Return>",evaluate)
```

[image]