# Fix _tkinter.TclError: no events specified in binding

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Got this code from somewhere online. I looked at the other SO answer but it didn't work for me. What should I fix this error
Question: [How to fix "- _tkinter.TclError: no events specified in binding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56343229/how-to-fix-tkinter-tclerror-no-events-specified-in-binding)

```
import tkinter as tk

fields = ['Email', 'Password', 'School']

def fetch(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text  = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

def makeform(root, fields):
    entries = []
    for field in fields:
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
        entries.append((field, ent))
    return entries

def getCreds():
    root = tk.Tk()
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
    root.bind('', (lambda events=ents: fetch(e)))   
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Show',
                  command=(lambda events=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()

getCreds()
```

Comment: What do you think this code is supposed to do? `root.bind('', (lambda events=ents: fetch(e))) `?

Comment: I'm guessing that the code binds fetch(exp) to the lambda (on click?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> _tkinter.TclError: no events specified in binding

This should be relatively obvious. If you look at any of the many many examples of `bind()` on SO or google you will find that the first argument always has something specific in it and never an empty string.

Take some time to read up on [tkinter-events-and-bindings](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

There are 2 problems with you `root.bind()` 1st any time you click anywhere on the screen it will call the function. This is likely not what you want.

The 2nd problem both with your bind and the button command is your lambda. `events=ents: fetch(e)` you define your list of entries as `events` but then pass `e` to the function. So you have to correct that.

Personally I would create the list in the same place you define the root as well as define the root in the global name space. This will allow us to avoid the lambda as well.

```
import tkinter as tk

fields = ['Email', 'Password', 'School']


def fetch(_=None):
    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entries):
        print('{}: {}'.format(fields[ndex], entry.get()))


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(background='gray')
entries = []
for ndex, field in enumerate(fields):
    tk.Label(root, width=15, text=field, anchor='w').grid(row=ndex, column=0, sticky='ew')
    entries.append(tk.Entry(root))
    entries[-1].grid(row=ndex, column=1, sticky='ew')

# The problem with root.bind is that it will constantly be calling the function anywhere you click on root.
root.bind('<Button-1>', fetch)
tk.Button(root, text='Show', command=fetch).grid(row=len(fields)+1, column=1, sticky='ew')
tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=len(fields)+2, column=1, sticky='ew')
root.mainloop()
```